# PCIe raid controller in a PCIe slot for GPU

Tags: motherboard, raid, pci-express, chipset, amd-ryzen

I have 3 components:

- Ryzen 1600X CPU
- Asus X370-PRO Motherboard
- ARECA ARC-1880DI-IX-12 Raid controller

My question is that if it's possible to put and use the raid controller in one of the mobo's PCIe 2.0/3.0 x16 slot that usually has a graphics cards and use these slots as 8x/8x just like if it was a graphics cards.
Also, is that possible to use a PCIe x1 graphics card in any of the PCIe 2.0 x1 slots on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Is it] possible to put and use the raid controller in one of the mobo's PCIe 2.0/3.0 x16 slot that usually has a graphics cards and use these slots as 8x/8x just like if it was a graphics cards.

Yes. That's what they are for. These slots are not limited to graphics cards. The amount of PCIe-Lanes that you assign to a slot can (almost always) be configured in the BIOS. You have to look in your Mainboard's manual to find out the possible combinations, they are always mentioned there.

> [Is it] possible to use a PCIe x1 graphics card in any of the PCIe 2.0 x1 slots on the board?

Also yes. If you've got one of these (rare) PCIe-x1 graphics cards, you can of course put them into an x1-slot.

Comment: Thank you for the response, to be honest what confused me is this article [link](https://rog.asus.com/articles/technologies/your-guide-to-the-ryzen-am4-platform-and-its-x370-b350-and-a320-chipsets/) It says that "Those PCIe lanes are reserved for graphics cards"

Comment: @DaTi: I have never read about any restriction in using PCI-E ports. They are universal ports that can serve any purpose. Back in the days there was the [AGP port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Graphics_Port) which was reserved for graphics cards, but nowadays [PCI-Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) is universal.

Comment: A quote from [Form factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Form_factors): "A PCI Express card fits into a slot of its physical size or larger (with ×16 as the largest used), but may not fit into a smaller PCI Express slot; for example, a ×16 card may not fit into a ×4 or ×8 slot. ".